# Convertion from apple video file to "universal" viewable for everyone when uploaded

Tags: video

I would like to ask how it is possible to convert an iPhone recorded video to another file, so I can make the videofile viewable here in SP when I uplaod.. Only Apple users are allowed to see it, is there something I can do about it in order to make it possible for everyone to watch the videofile?